# Can't display images with shadows and scroll smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, performance, swiftui

My app involves displaying <100 image thumbnails and for some reason my iPad Pro 2018 is struggling to scroll through the images smoothly. I recreated a simplified example below. The image is 200px square.

Replacing the images with colored rectangles eliminates the lag. Removing the shadow also removes the lag. I think rendering 50 images with a shadow should be within my device's capabilities, but let me know if anyone disagrees.

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {

            let gridLayout = [(GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 160)))]

            LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, spacing: 8) {
                ForEach(0..<50) { index in
                    Image("cookie_200")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                        .padding(8)
                        .shadow(radius: 4)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Question**
Is there a less performance-intensive way to show these thumbnails?

Screen capture with shadow (laggy scroll):
https://share.icloud.com/photos/04eFNISH1khfkFqgAmGfGJJZw

Screen capture without shadow (smooth):
https://share.icloud.com/photos/02etl7kVG30Cnc6cr_dwSJK-Q

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shadows and transparency make the runtime do a lot of work. Hence the lag.

> Question Is there a less performance-intensive way to show these thumbnails?

Yes. Instead of making the runtime draw the shadows, *you* draw the shadows. In particular you make an image consisting of the thumbnail and the shadow, on an *opaque* background the same color as your view background. Now scrolling is perfectly performant.